Cannot update homebrew - possible permission issue?
Disclaimer: I am using a company managed machine, I am on a VPN and I have 0 experience as a developer - getting homebrew working as Step 1 for a Udemy course on Dart/Flutter I am taking.
When typing in % brew update && brew doctor into Terminal, here is my output. (This is a similar error I am getting when trying to use a version manager to install a new version of Ruby (outside of the system ruby) as a pre-requisite to installing cocoapods.)
==> Updating Homebrew...
Error: Failed to download https://formulae.brew.sh/api/formula.jws.json!
Failed to download https://formulae.brew.sh/api/cask.jws.json!
Failed to download https://formulae.brew.sh/api/formula_tap_migrations.jws.json!
Failed to download https://formulae.brew.sh/api/cask_tap_migrations.jws.json!
==> Downloading https://formulae.brew.sh/api/formula.jws.json
Warning: Failed to open the file                                                              
Warning: /Users/m306928/Library/Caches/Homebrew/api/formula.jws.json: 
Warning: Permission denied
curl: (56) Failure writing output to destination, passed 2776 returned 4294967295

Error: Failure while executing; `/usr/bin/env /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/shims/shared/curl --disable --cookie /dev/null --globoff --user-agent Homebrew/4.4.11\ \(Macintosh\;\ Intel\ Mac\ OS\ X\ 14.7\)\ curl/8.7.1 --header Accept-Language:\ en --fail --progress-bar --remote-time --output /Users/m306928/Library/Caches/Homebrew/api/formula.jws.json --location --disable --cookie /dev/null --globoff --show-error --user-agent Homebrew/4.4.11\ \(Macintosh\;\ Intel\ Mac\ OS\ X\ 14.7\)\ curl/8.7.1 --header Accept-Language:\ en --fail --progress-bar --compressed --speed-limit 100 --speed-time 5 https://formulae.brew.sh/api/formula.jws.json` exited with 56. Here's the output:
Warning: Failed to open the file                                                              
Warning: /Users/m306928/Library/Caches/Homebrew/api/formula.jws.json: 
Warning: Permission denied
curl: (56) Failure writing output to destination, passed 2776 returned 4294967295


I'm stuck at this point!

you can try adding sudo before command. for example: sudo brew update. It gives access to terminal as logged in user

@HitarthChhunchha when I do this, I get the following error:
'Error: Running Homebrew as root is extremely dangerous and no longer supported.
As Homebrew does not drop privileges on installation you would be giving all
build scripts full access to your system.'

I think it is the folder ownership issue,
Warning: Failed to open the file
Warning: /Users/m306928/Library/Caches/Homebrew/api/formula.jws.json:
Warning: Permission denied
curl: (56) Failure writing output to destination

you can try doing
sudo chown -R $(whoami) /Users/m306928/Library/Caches/Homebrew

